# Is Gautami a suitable font for general purpose greeting card with abstract photography image

Tags: adobe-indesign, font-recommendation

What standard fonts available for Adobe Indesign Cs6 Windows suitable for writing the text on the back of a set of greeting cards that display modern photographic abstract images.  ( you can browse some images at http://www.secretdorsetphoto.com )

e.g

[image]
I am trying to create cards of some of photographs. But I am not a designer and I am struggling to decide on a suitable font, currently I have picked Gautami.

I have had this problem before when generating websites, I am well aware that picking the wrong font can have a really detrimental effect on the finished product.

I have asked for a standard font partly because I do not want the hassle/expense of installing additional fonts but mainly because I don't want the company that is going to do the printing to have problems installing the font.

**Edit**
Based on some of the suggestions I have a new version, note I didnt make it clear this is a greeting card and so it has front and back which isnt immediately apparent from the way I have done it, so Ive just uploaded the back

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question? *is stumped*

Comment: @Vincent sorry the font is for greeting card - Ive added more information

Comment: What is 'suitable' will, alas, be heavily opinion based.

Comment: I'm just asking for a some options from people with more experience than I.

Comment: @DAO1 Ive limited the scope of the question by just asking if the font Ive chosen is suitable for its purpose

Comment: ".. because I don't want the company that is going to do the printing to have problems installing the font" – erm, you should send them a PDF. Do ask them what kind of PDF before you do that. (And, conversely, if they *want* your original InDesign file, tell 'em an actual professional told you to that's bad practice.)

Comment: @jongware you are correct they actual want the pdf I didnt realize that so there isnt an issue with them installing fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A critique

As it is, your text appears too prominent – it attracts attention. While in general not a bad thing, it *is* when the reader's focus should be on the artwork, not "distracted" by the accompanying text.

The text appears prominent because

1. The font size is quite large.
2. The font itself is quite dark.
3. The text is closely spaced, so there are dense blocks of data.

In addition, a couple of minor points:

4. The text is in black.
5. The text uses lots of capitals.

You can try a different approach for each of these points, alone or in combination with others:

1. A smaller font size,
2. a lighter font cut,
3. a larger line height ("leading"),
4. a tint of black, or possibly an actual color,
5. a font that has less prominent capitals; or, for that distinct sense of 'design', use as much lowercase as you can (which will make the capitalized phrases stand out more),
6. Some additional tracking to space out the text.

#### An apology

Is it so 'orrible then? Well no :)

Things that you definitely got right are (1) using a sans serif font for a relatively distant, objective, informative, clean text, (2) an attractive global layout with all main elements centered and a repetition of the 'important' image, (3) lots of white space on the left hand side, to counteract the full page image on the right hand side.

#### A suggestion

There are not that many really *really* good fonts that come with your computer– wait, let me rephrase that. There are lots of actually very good fonts that come with your computer, but that is no reason not to look beyond those!

Here is my proposal for the text, using a smaller font, lots more spacing, a 60% shade of black for the text, and a *free* font: Droid Sans. Also I got rid of a few of the capitals. The text is spaced out using +20 tracking, as with its default this font looks a bit cramped to me.

Consider making the right hand side larger – make it so large it bleeds off the page: "dramatically", rather than having a boring standard white border.

Be careful picking a color for your text. It should not (again) distract too much so don't pick a glaringly bright color. In addition, a color that matches one particular illustration may not match another well (although you could counteract this with picking a specific color for each different image). In my proposal I chose a light tint of gray, hence neutral for most images.

[image: dorset photography]

Comment: Thanks Jongware that is really good advise. I didnt make it clear that it is a card and hence has back and front you cant see both at same time when folded. I thought myself the text looked a bit black and too large but never occurred to print as grey, i reduce the black to 71%. I have not tried the new font yet or changed spacing and capitals yet but I will give that a go

Answer (score 0):

Picking a font is really dependent off of the intended use of the art and the receipent(s).

For example you wouldn't use a hard sans-serif font like Arial for a get well soon card.

I would check out some top 10/20 font lists [like this one](http://www.mostinspired.com/blog/2010/08/12/20-free-fonts-ideal-for-your-greeting-cards/) to compare fonts with your artwork and pick a suitable one!

The key here is to match the mood with the softness or hardness of the font.

Bear in mind that these aren't exactly the "correct" terms to describe font characteristics but I'm using less technical terms.

Comment: Good general  advice about picking font for intended use, however in this case its a general purpose card that could be used for any purpose I suppose people would buy it because they like the image and/or they want a memento of a holiday/short break to the area - Im trying to appeal to people who want a less cliched card of the area so I imagine the person who buys this would be most likely be younger/design orientated. I want to use a font available with indesign